# Make 3 div react as closely as possible to video

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make my final result look something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRVtplLrkxk
We have 3 divs lined up horionzontally. The image div is in the center of the 3 div and the rest of the 2 div just contain random letters. I also want my image to keep its aspect ratio as it resize.
Can the flexibility be accomplish using any JavaScript?

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-block text-block-one">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <h1>Hello there</h1>
      <h3>et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat  </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-block">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x750">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-block text-block-two">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <h3>et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my scss:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #efefef;
}
h1,h2,h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;

  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  
  
  .text-block {
    width: 37.645448%;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    padding-top: 250px;
    
    .text-wrapper {
      margin: 0 10%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
  }
  
  .image-block {

    .image-container {
      
    }
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this CSS:

```
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
 .image-block{
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
  }
  img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .text-block {
    width: 33%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .text-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  h3 {
    margin: 0 25px;
  }
```

same as of videos

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is written as SASS (it should be interpreted and rendered CSS, but it's out of the scope here), and I wrote your CSS in actual CSS structure and limited the width of the picture container to 450px, now it looks fine to me:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #efefef;
}
h1,h2,h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}  
   
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}      
.text-block {
    width: 37.645448%;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    padding-top: 250px;        
}
.text-wrapper {
    margin: 0 10%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.image-container {
  max-width: 450px;    
}
```

See the result here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ypt1vfs3/

Hope that's what you meant to accomplish.

Comment: Your addition of max-width didnt change anything for me ;/